# Is there an easy way to get the image derivatives links?

Tags: 8, media

I'm working with complex image styles, and I'd like to be able to load all the different derivatives quickly to check they're being processed correctly.

But I don't see how to easily get the links. The best I can come up with is opening the node in JSONAPI and, with the patch from https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2825812, getting the URLs for derivatives from that.

It there something easier?

Back in the Drupal 6 days, the Image module showed the links to all the sizes on the image node itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can get that info with the following code:

```
$original_uri = 'public://images/image.jpg';

$styles = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('image_style')->loadMultiple();

$urls = array_map(function($style) use ($original_uri) {
  return $style->buildUri($original_uri);
}, $styles);
```

`$urls` should now contain a list of URLs based on the original, one for each image style in the system.

Answer (score 1):

To get the image derivative URI for an image to which is applied a specific image style, you can use the following code.

```php
// Load the ImageStyle instance in $image_style, for example with
// $image_style = ImageStyle::load($id).
// $image_uri is the path/URI for the image to which the style is applied. 
if ($image_style->supportsUri($image_uri)) {
  $derivative_uri = $style->buildUri($image_uri);
}
```

Keep in mind that image derivatives are created only when the URL returned from `$image_style->buildURL($image_uri)` is requested (from a browser). Building the URI (or the URL) doesn't generate the derivative image; it returns the URI (URL) for an image that couldn't exist, yet.

To check an image derivative could be created, code similar to the one used from [`ImageStyleDownloadController::deliver()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21image%21src%21Controller%21ImageStyleDownloadController.php/function/ImageStyleDownloadController%3A%3Adeliver/8.9.x) should be used.

```php
if ($image_style->supportsUri($image_uri)) {
  $derivative_uri = $style->buildUri($image_uri);

  if (!file_exists($image_uri)) {
    $path_info = pathinfo($image_uri);
    $converted_image_uri = $path_info['dirname'] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $path_info['filename'];
    if (file_exists($converted_image_uri)) {
      $image_uri = $converted_image_uri;
    }
  }

  $success = file_exists($derivative_uri) || $image_style->createDerivative($image_uri, $derivative_uri);

  if ($success) {
    $image = Drupal::service('image.factory')->get($derivative_uri);
    $uri = $image->getSource();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! What I meant though is whether there's a way of getting those out in the UI. Content editors, for example, may want to verify the derivative images quickly.

Comment: I don't know of any module that does that. A custom module that uses the code I suggest can show the URIs on a page.